# C# Local Variable

Tags: c#, variables, local

Can somebody please explain why I get:

> "use of unassigned local variable number_of_column" for: if (i < number_of_column -1)

and what is the best way to handle this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    int number_of_column;
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        var file = dir.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
        string file1 = file.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(file1);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path + "\\" + file1);
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (start == true)
            {
                string[] line1 = line.Split(',');
                number_of_column = line1.Count();
                i = 0;
                foreach (string s in line1)
                {
                    if ((s != "0") || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
                    {
                        col[i] = "checked";

                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (line.Contains("Timestamp") && line.Contains("LiveStandby") && line.Contains("peak"))
                {
                    start = true;

                }
            }
        }
        sr.Close();

        i=0;
        foreach (string s in col)
        {
            if (i < number_of_column -1)
            {
```

Comment: Think about why you declare `number_of_column` at all would be the first step to solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you never enter the while loop, the variable has no assigned value.

If you hit the else branch in your if, the variable has no assigned value.

These are the reasons you get this error message.

You can fix this by assigning a value when you declare the variable.

C# requires you to initialize local variables before you use them. 
For member variables this is not necessary, they get their default value assigned automatically.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek it looks like it's in the foreach loop after that

Answer (score 2):

Totally refined of your code

1. `file` then `file1` was just redundant, the statements can be merged and been even better semantically meaningful.
2. `if (start == true)` is unnecessarily complicated, just `if(start)`
3. Use [`using Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) woule be better to ensure the correct use of `IDisposable` like `StreamReader`.
4. There's [`Path.Combine Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to combine two strings into a path.
5. The two `foreach`s is better to be `for`, since you are iterating on arrays sequentially.
6. It's not difficult to figure out that `number_of_column` is not necessary to used that you are just storing the counts for iteration of arrays.

---

code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int number_of_column; // never used

    if(Directory.Exists(path)) {
        var file1=(
            from f in dir.GetFiles()
            orderby f.LastWriteTime
            select f
            ).First().ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(file1);

        using(var sr=new StreamReader(Path.Combine(path, file1)))
            for(String line; null!=(line=sr.ReadLine()); ) {
                if(start) {
                    var line1=line.Split(',');

                    for(var i=0; i<line1.Length; ++i) {
                        var s=line1[i];

                        if("0"!=s||!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                            col[i]="checked";
                    }

                    continue;
                }

                if(
                    line.Contains("Timestamp")
                    &&
                    line.Contains("LiveStandby")
                    &&
                    line.Contains("peak"
                    ))
                    start=true;
            }

        for(var i=0; i<col.Length; ++i) {
            // following lines are no more needed
            // if(i<number_of_column-1) {
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your first line to:

```
static void Main(string[] args){ int number_of_column = 0;if (Directory.Exists(path))
```

or formatted:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int number_of_column = 0;
    if (Directory.Exists(path)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you are not assigning any initial value into it.

Replace this

```
int number_of_column;
```

With

```
int number_of_column = 0;
```

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a mechanism to prevent side-effects, C# does not allow the use of uninitialized variables - variables declared, but having no explicitly set value. That's why you get the error. Initializing it to zero resolves the problem.